# Laravel active menu item for url included parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set active class in my list item, but it doesn't work.

My code in blade:

```
@foreach($data as $site)
  <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="second-menu">
  @if(isAdmin())<li class="{{-- active class  for url parameter --}}"><a href="{{ url('sites/'.$site->id.'/edit') }}" >{{ $site->name }}</a></li>
@endif
</ul>
@endforeach
```

So, if I write: li class="@if(getRouteName() == 'site@index'){{ 'active' }}@endif" , it works nice, but in my case the problem is that I want to get **'active'** class in foreach **sites/'.$site->id.'/edit**

Many thanks.

Comment: Pass from Controller to view ID of the current Site you are on, and if this ID == site id in foreach, place active class.

Comment: Can you update so that you include the whole `foreach` in your post? Right now it's not clear what you're foreaching (<ul> and <li> within it?)

Comment: simple and useful . Thank you

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use [`is()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#request-path-and-method) method. For example:

```
<li class="{{ request()->is('sites/*/edit') ? 'active' : '' }}"
```

Comment: Excellent!  it works nice. The code: Request::is('sites/'.$site->id.'/edit') ? 'active' : ''

Answer (score 26):

I am currently using Laravel 5.6.* and my solution is:

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link {{ request()->is('users*') ? 'active' : '' }}">Users</a>
```

Answer (score 24):

There is also the following if you have named your route :

```
<li class="{{ Request::routeIs('admin') ? 'active' : '' }}">...</li>
```

[Inspired from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50655430/8452283)

Comment: This solution is perfect. For named Routes:   {{ Request::routeIs('users.*') ? 'active' : '' }}

Answer (score 10):

You can try this as well

```
<a href="#" class="{{ (\Request::route()->getName() == 'put the address of your route here or your route name') ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

e.g:

```
<a href="#" class="{{ (\Request::route()->getName() == 'admin') ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

Note: I only test in Laravel 5.5

Comment: It was solution for what i need . Thanks a lot ^_^

Answer (score 9):

Make a function in **helper**.

```
function activeMenu($uri = '') {
    $active = '';
    if (Request::is(Request::segment(1) . '/' . $uri . '/*') || Request::is(Request::segment(1) . '/' . $uri) || Request::is($uri)) {
        $active = 'active';
    }
    return $active;
}
```

Use it in sidebar.

```
<li class="{{ activeMenu('dashboard') }}"></li>
<li class="{{ activeMenu('student') }}"></li>
<li class="{{ activeMenu('teacher') }}"></li>
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using Laravel 7 and Bootstrap Dropdown. So there are several collapse items that depend on the link, this works:

```
<li class="nav-item {{ Route::is('users.*') || Route::is('user.*')  ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

Answer (score 3):

**First i am gonna shear my opinion then you can vote or nonvoter.**

1. **First you want to active your menu using path so you can use bellow code.**

   > {{  request()->path() === 'admin/orders' ? 'your_active_class' : '' }}
2. **Second if you want active your menu using query parameter so you can
   use bellow code.**

   > {{ request()->query('status') === 'processing' ? 'your_active_class' :
   > '' }}
3. **Third using name route**

> request()->routeIs('admin.cities')

Or even sub-routes (like editing, creating, or whatever with

```
request()->routeIs('admin.cities*')
```

If you prefer to use the route facade, you still can do that with

```
 Route::named('admin.cities*')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//my admin.app.blade file
<ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item @yield('query')">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('query_page')}}">
          <i class="material-icons">query_builder</i>
          <p>Queries</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item @yield('feedback')">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('feedback_page')}}">
          <i class="material-icons">feedback</i>
          <p>Feedback</p>
        </a>
      </li>
  </ul>

     //query.blade
     @extends('admin.app')
     @section('title', 'Query Manager')
     @section('page-heading', 'Query Manager')
     @section('query','active')



     //feedback.blade
     @extends('admin.app')
     @section('title', 'Feedback Manager')
     @section('page-heading', 'Feedback Manager')
     @section('feedback','active')
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22687192)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 7+

For named routes with prefixes like `admin` or `admin.view` or `admin.edit` etc...

```php
<li class="{{ Str::startsWith(Route::currentRouteName(), 'admin')) ? 'active' : '' }}">...</li>
```

A bit verbose but you can look into making a custom function like `is_active('admin')`

Answer (score 1):

I like more to use this syntax to check the route since has not been mentioned.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link {{ request()->routeIs('team*') ? 'active font-weight-bolder' : '' }}">Teams</a>
</li>
```

Two more things:

- Adding an asterisk, without a dot as route name will target all the routes that start with team, teams, etc.
- If you are using any CSS framework like Bootstrap or Tailwind you can add here also the classes to style the menu item, instead of writing some CSS for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use short if.
Example:

```
<a href="#" class="{{ (\Request::route()->getName() == 'this.route') ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

Comment: Same, it didn't work. It must detect id of page, because it doesn't know in which page it is. The id is variable for each page.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, make a function in **helper** and autoload it.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    },
    "files": [
        "helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

```php
// helpers/helpers.php

if (!function_exists('selected')) {
    function selected($routeName, $parameters = [], $class = 'active')
    {
        if (!route_has($routeName)) {
            return '';
        }

        return '/' . request()->path() == route($routeName, $parameters, false) ? $class : '';
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="{{ route('example_route_name', [], false) }}" class="{{ selected('example_route_name', []) }}">Menu
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to use inline CSS, then use the solution below(Currently using Laravel 8).

```
     <ul>
         <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}" style="{{ request()->is('/') ? 'color: #F9A82D;' : '' }}">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{ url('/profile') }} " style="{{ request()->is('/profile') ? 'color: #F9A82D;' : '' }}">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
```

For links with parameters for example **http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/{id}** use **"request()->is('/user/*')".** see example below:

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/user{id}') }} " style="{{ request()->is('/user/*') ? 'color: #F9A82D;' : '' }}">User</a></li>
```

[reference](https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/laravel-how-to-make-menu-item-active-by-urlroute/)

your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using request segments to make current menu active.    [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uN5JNTEWGEo&ab_channel=LaravelDaily)

```
<li class="{{ (request()->segment(2) == 'home') ? 'active' : '' }}" >
    <a href="{{ url('home') }}">Home</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8

//http://my_salat.test/dashboard/owner/services/create

blade | class active : edit & create & index => pages

```
{{ request()->segment(3) == 'services' ? 'active' : '' }}
```

segment(3) number word URL route => services

Answer (score -1):

is('admin/restaurant/create*')) ? 'active' : '' }}>

.active { background-color: #7dd3f6; }

Comment: try this code for your every navbar link according to your route name(admin/restaurant/create).

Comment: please edit your answer and add you're written comment to that