# using Request::is() function with named Routes Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I was doing `Request::is('/')` which gave me `true` for `example.com` Now I am using named routes and for the name `welcome`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('admin_panel.welcome');
})->name('welcome');
```

`Request::is(route('welcome'))` returns `false`

What should I do. Note: I am using this for active states in navigation

Comment: $request->route()->named('welcome') see [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `routeIs` method:

```
Request::routeIs('welcome');
```

Comment: and how to acheive ````Route::is('sometext/*')```` with named routes?

Comment: @AhmedNawazKhan Pretty much the same way. You would just need to have something like a common prefix in the name e.g. `sometext-foo` and `sometext-bar` would be `routeIs('sometext-*')`

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using `Request::url() == route('welcome')`which gave me `true`for `example.com`