# How to check if the current route doesn't have prefix?

Tags: laravel

I have 2 kind of routes. For Admin, all of my routes are always have an admin prefix. For User, it doesn't have any prefix at all.

I'm able check if the currect route has admin prefix by using this code:

```
Route::current()->getPrefix() === '/admin'
```

But when I tried to do the same for non-prefix (the User) routes, it doesn't work:

```
Route::current()->getPrefix() === '/'
```

How am I supposed to check if the current route doesn't have prefix? I know I can technically just reverse the logic by using:

```
Route::current()->getPrefix() !== '/admin'
```

But I wanted something different so that I don't get confused easily in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using these checks multiple times in your code, if this is the case I would add 2 helper functions and call them accordingly. Then you'll have 2 functions that are named differently, so easier to distinguish. Other than that you could also extend the Route facade and implement your custom functions.

Comment: i would assume if it doesn't have a prefix it would be `''` a blank string, not a `'/'` which is a redundant thing ... all paths are relative to the root so `'/'` is not going to be there as it isn't part of the prefix

Comment: @Aless55 One-time usage only as I just need it for my login screen, all of the other related pages are handled by a different logic.

Answer (score 0):

As described in my comment, you could extend the Route Facade like follows. This enables you to check the admin prefix like that `CustomRoute::hasPrefix("/admin");`

```
    <?php
    
    namespace <YOUR NAMESPACE HERE>;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    class CustomRoute extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route
    {
      public static function hasPrefix(String $prefix) : bool{
        return Route::current()->getPrefix() === $prefix;
      }

      public static function doesntHavePrefix(String $prefix) : bool{
        return !self::hasPrefix($prefix);
      }
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to extend a facade or the router itself ... you can "macro" methods onto that underlying class at run time: `Route::macro('hasPrefix', ....)` ... you could potentially have these methods macroed on the `Route` class instead of the `Router`, depending on the need

Comment: Is this equally as performant as using an extended class?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way might be

```
{{ !(Route::is('admin/index')) }}
!(Request::routeIs('welcome'));
```

There is already simmilar topic:
[using Request::is() function with named Routes Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655365/using-requestis-function-with-named-routes-laravel)