# Apply "active" class on active url in Laravel dynamically, what is the clean and reusable way?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For the following URLs:

- http://localhost/admin/users
- http://localhost/admin/users/create
- http://localhost/admin/users/profile/1

I want to apply class "active" to users navigation dynamically in Laravel as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="{{ route('users') }}">Users</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="{{ route('pages') }}">Pages</a></li>
</ul>
```

What is the clean and reusable way to do this without using third party plugins?

Comment: I use this package: [laravelista/Ekko](https://github.com/laravelista/Ekko), it has some cool functions.

Comment: That is a good package but I wanted to do it without using additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Single line shortcut solution**

> Use {{ request()->is('*users*') ? 'active' : '' }} as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51337810/3528202) as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li class="{{ request()->is('*users*') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{ route('users') }}">Users</a></li>
    <li class="{{ request()->is('*pages*') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{ route('pages') }}">Pages</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Method 2: Clean and reusable solution**

You can create and use a custom helper named "active" by following these steps:

> 1. Add {{ active('partial-url') }} in your class attribute

```
<ul>
    <li class="{{ active('users') }}"><a href="{{ route('users') }}">Users</a></li>
    <li class="{{ active('pages') }}"><a href="{{ route('pages') }}">Pages</a></li>
</ul>
```

> 2. Create a file named "helpers.php" in your app directory and add this helper function

```
<?php
function active($partialUrl){
      return request()->is("*".$partialUrl."*") ? 'active' : '';
}
```

> 3. Add the helpers.php file to autoload by adding the following line in your composer.json file

```
    ...
     "autoload": {
          ...
          "files": [
              ...
              "app/helpers.php",
          ],
          ...
    },
   ...
```

*"..." in above code snipet means that there may or may not be some other lines of code*

> 4. Dump the auto-loader by running the following command

```
composer dump-autoload
```