# How can I add active class in Laravel on header items when they're clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I've been trying to get active class on my header items when they are clicked. I have a menu and my li items inside of a menu leads to specific pages on my website. Now I want to add active class on them when they're clicked, it's easy when the website is only HTML and CSS but how can I do it in php, to be more specific Laravel? I include my header in all of the pages.

My header.php code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="width: 43.333333% !important;position: relative;right: 1.35rem;margin-bottom: 12px;"> 

<!-- Nav start -->

<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="nav-main">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="{{ Request::url() == route('index') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a id="newmenu" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);" href="{{url('/')}}">{{__('Beauty treatments')}}</a> </li>
                            @foreach($show_in_top_menu as $top_menu) @php $cmsContent = App\CmsContent::getContentBySlug($top_menu->page_slug); @endphp
                            <li class="{{ Request::url() == route('cms', $top_menu->page_slug) ? 'active' : '' }}"><a id="newmenu" href="/demo/public/jobs?country_id%5B%5D=231">{{__('Hair')}}</a> </li>
                            @endforeach 

                            <li class="{{ Request::url() == route('index') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a id="newmenu" href="{{url('/')}}">{{__('Hands')}}</a> </li>
                             <li class="{{ Request::url() == route('index') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a id="newmenu" href="{{url('/')}}">{{__('Spa Services')}}</a> </li>

</ul>

<!-- Nav collapes end --> 

 </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<!-- Nav end --> 

</div>
</div>

<!-- row end --> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menunew:active {background-color: #07c;color: #fff;}
```

JS:

```
 $('li a').click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Can anone please help me, im stuck and I don't know what should I do, I tried examples from here but nothing seems to work, best wishes!

Comment: if the links redirect to a new page you won' t be able to make them active with jquery/javascipt
i did the active part with a variable that i set in the controller and then checked in the header before printing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel active menu item for url included parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937494/laravel-active-menu-item-for-url-included-parameters)

Comment: Can someone please make an example of my code for this? I keep trying things from the thread @GingerCSSWizard sended but I cant achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, this is from the linked thread and https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#request-path-and-method:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="width: 43.333333% !important;position: relative;right: 1.35rem;margin-bottom: 12px;">

      <!-- Nav start -->

      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="nav-main">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="{{ request()->is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a id="newmenu" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);" href="{{url('/')}}">{{__('Beauty treatments')}}</a> </li>
            @foreach($show_in_top_menu as $top_menu) @php $cmsContent = App\CmsContent::getContentBySlug($top_menu->page_slug); @endphp
            <li class="{{ request()->is('cms/*') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a id="newmenu" href="/demo/public/jobs?country_id%5B%5D=231">{{__('Hair')}}</a> </li>
            @endforeach

            <li class="{{ request()->is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a id="newmenu" href="{{url('/')}}">{{__('Hands')}}</a> </li>
            <li class="{{ request()->is('/') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a id="newmenu" href="{{url('/')}}">{{__('Spa Services')}}</a> </li>

          </ul>

          <!-- Nav collapes end -->

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Nav end -->

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- row end -->
</div>
```

Comment: Its not working bro, any chance i can send you the ftp access and you can try it on your own?

Answer (score 0):

I usually go the way of setting a variable like the comment above and handle this through the middleware in Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware.

I create a middleware using artisan and ensure the routes go through it.

`php artisan make:middleware ActiveNav`

```
// routes/web.php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'active.nav'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@index');
    Route::get('/blog', 'BlogController@index');
});
```

Register the middleware in kernel.php (notice the last line in the array)

```
// app/Http/Kernel.php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'active.nav' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetActiveNav::class,
];
```

I then check the route in the middleware and set a variable which I share with the Views

```
// app/Http/Middleware/ActiveNav.php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $active['home']     = '';
    $active['contact']  = '';
    $active['blog']     = '';

    $route = $request->getPathInfo();

    switch(true) {
        case(strstr($route, '/blog')) :
            $active['blog'] = 'active';
            break;
        case(strstr($route, '/contact')) :
            $active['contact'] = 'active';
            break;
        default:
            $active['home'] = 'active';
    }

    \View::share('active', $active );

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

Then I check in the nav:

```
// nav.blade.php
<li class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link {{$active['home']}} btn" href="/">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link {{$active['blog']}}" href="/blog">Blog</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link {{$active['contact']}}" href="/contact">Contact</a>
</li>
```

You can use middleware whenever you need to run a certain function on a route (or a group of routes). Also no JS required this way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a custom helper method inside a [helper](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) file:

```
if(!function_exists('is_active_menu')){

    function is_active_menu($url){

        return \Route::is($url) ? 'active' : '';
    }

}
```

and then use :

```
<li class="list-item {{ is_active_menu('home') }} ">Men</li>
```

You can use wildcards like `home*` in `is()` function.

Comment: Its not working bro or I dont know how to do it, any chance i can send you the ftp access and you can try it on your own? –

Answer (score 0):

You can use **is** method of **request** function
The **is** method allows you to verify that the incoming request path matches a given pattern.
For example:

- If your url is www.yourdomain.com

```
<li class="{{request()->is('/') ? 'active' : ''}}"></li>
```

- If yur url is www.yourdoamin.com/page1

```
<li class="{{request()->is('page1') ? 'active' : ''}}"></li>
```

- If yur url is www.yourdoamin.com/page1/category1

```
<li class="{{request()->is('page1/category1') ? 'active' : ''}}"></li>
```

- You may use the * character as a wildcard.

  www.yourdomain.com/page1/category1

```
<li class="{{request()->is('page1/*') ? 'active' : ''}}"></li>
```

- www.yourdomain.com/page1/category1/subcategory1

```
<li class="{{request()->is('page1/*') ? 'active' : ''}}"></li>
```

Docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests