# Add Active Class to sidebar Item Based on URL

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using laravel and when the page is refresh the active item  on sidebar is not selected, `this : li class="{{ (request()->is('admin/cities*')) ? 'active' : '' }}">` (is a easy solution), but not looks great.  How i can make this using jquery or other?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul li a').click(function() {
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
<style>.sidebar-link.active,
.sidebar-link:focus {
  background: #e2e8ed;
  color: grey !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar py-3">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu list-unstyled">

    <li class="sidebar-list-item"><a href="/test" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted active"><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Dashboard</span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="sidebar-list-item"><a href="/test2" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted"><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Test</span></a>
    </li>
    <ul>

</div>
```

Comment: if  you want to do it in client side you can use local storage to store the current status of the anchor and just retrieve that status on load.

Comment: If you're looking for a Laravel solution , you can use middleware. I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674931/how-can-i-add-active-class-in-laravel-on-header-items-when-theyre-clicked/54680902#54680902 :)